# Failed to run xelatex when trying to convert jupyter notebook to pdf

Tags: python, jupyter, pandoc, nbconvert

I am trying to get my jupyter notebook to convert to pdf so I can submit it, and am having an awfully hard time doing so. I first installed nbconvert and pypandoc and then I downloaded the pandoc zip folder on their website (the installer wasn't working) and put it in my path. I was initially getting the message

```
nbconvert failed: Pandoc wasn't found. Please check that pandoc is installed: http://pandoc.org/installing.html
```

but doing those steps fixed it. I am now getting the following message. I did a workaround solution by print previewing, saving the html page, and then converting the html page to pdf, but it would still be nice to fix this. Thanks!

```
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
Failed to run "xelatex .\notebook.tex -quiet" command:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> .\notebook
              .tex -quiet
? 
! Emergency stop.
<*> .\notebook
              .tex -quiet
No pages of output.
Transcript written on ?.
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved with

```
pip install --upgrade --user nbconvert
```